# AWS CloudFormation: Load Balancer Internet Gateway? Bucket creation resulting AccessControl only 1 out of 2 subschema matches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

**Problem Load Balancer Internet Gateway to Subnets**

**Problem 1 ? **

Resources Load Balancer resulting from a missing internet gateway to pass through VPC AWS resource, not created on YAML stack.

**Potential solution to 1st problem question**

UPDATED

```
  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref VPC
```

For this solution, I think I have correctly pointed Subnet1/Subnet2 to propertiy VpcID: IGateway, and the Load Balancer to reference Subnet1/Subnet2?

Is this a correct configuration for Load Balancer to internet gateway to pass through VPC AWS Subnet resources?

UPDATED But when I do this I have this error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid id: "VPC" (expecting "vpc-...") (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 27fe5338-7318-4b6e-b85d-d58acec58317)" (RequestToken: 88e938c2-9bae-ddfa-3e21-767f4a93164f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

UPDATED TargetGroup has error message

```
Resource handler returned message: "A protocol must be specified (Service: ElasticLoadBalancingV2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: f6a43395-3d07-4b88-9c8c-932c5d141749)" (RequestToken: 81f3fe8c-d3fc-591d-40aa-7428b71eae02, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

**Problem Bucket creation**

**Problem 2 ? **

I create the bucket resources as follows below. But I have this problem on AccessControl that indicated that only 1 subschema matches out of 2. So what exactly am I doing wrong on this AccessControl failed validation constraint?

```
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Description: Amazon S3 bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: !Ref ACL
```

```
Properties validation failed for resource Bucket with message: #/AccessControl: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/AccessControl: failed validation constraint for keyword [enum]
```

YAML Script for CloudFormation

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  ACL:
    Type: String
    Description: Would you like to apply a canned access control list to grant predefined permissions?
    # S3 Canned ACLs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl
    AllowedValues:
        # private - (Bucket & Object): Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. No one else has access rights. *default*
      - "Private"
        # public-read - (Bucket & Object): Owner gets FULL_CONTROL.  The AllUsers group gets READ access.
      - "PublicRead"
        # public-read-write - (Bucket & Object): Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. The AllUsers group gets READ and WRITE access. *Not generally recommended*
      - "PublicReadWrite"
        # aws-exec-read - (Bucket & Object): Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. Amazon EC2 gets READ access to GET an AMI bundle from Amazon S3.
      - "AwsExecRead"
        # authenitcated-read - (Bucket & Object): Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. The AuthenticatedUsers group gets READ access.
      - "AuthenticatedRead"
        # bucket-owner-read - (Object): Object owner gets FULL_CONTROL. Bucket owner gets READ access. *If specified at time of bucket creation, Amazon S3 ignores it*
      - "BucketOwnerRead"
        # bucket-owner-full-control - (Object): Both object owner and bucket owner get FULL_CONTROL over objects. *If specified at time of bucket creation, Amazon S3 ignores it*
      - "BucketOwnerFullControl"
        # log-delivery-write - (Bucket): The LogDelivery group gets WRITE and READ_ACP permissions on the bucket. *See S3 Server Access Logging for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html *
      - "LogDeliveryWrite"
        # none - (N/A): No canned ACL defined
      - "None"
    Default: "None"

  DBName:
    Default: awsRDB
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'

  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Description: Master username 
    Default: admin

  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    Description: Master password 
    Default: password

  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: instance class
    Type: String

  DBAllocStore:
    Default: '500'
    Description: GB size database
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '20'
    MaxValue: '65536'

  RBDBInstance2:
    Default: RBDBInstance
    Description: My RBD instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '80'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  KmsKeyId:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^([a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12})$"
    Default: "12345678-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-123456789abc"

Resources:

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC

  AWSBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Description: Amazon S3 bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: !Ref ACL

  IGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC Internet Gateway

  VPCGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref IGateway
      VpcId: VPC

  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.20.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1b'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: SubnetStack1
          Value: 'PrivateSubnet1'

  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.30.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 'us-east-1d'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: SubnetStack2
          Value: 'PublicSubnet2'

  SSHSecGrp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: Security group egress
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 127.0.0.111/32
          IpProtocol: "-1"
      depends_on: 
      - !Ref Subnet1
      - !Ref Subnet2
 
  EC2SecGrp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80

  EC2Net1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: 'ami-05c13eab67c5d8861'
      SecurityGroupIds: 
      - GetAtt: EC2SecGrp
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      KeyName: EC2Net1
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          #echo "<h1>Hello from Region us-east-1b</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html


  EC2Net2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: 'ami-05c13eab67c5d8861'
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref EC2SecGrp
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      KeyName: EC2Net2
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          #echo "<h1>Hello from Region us-east-1d</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html

  S3BuckPol:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref AWSBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:*'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${AWSBucket}/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/@matthew'

  LoadBalance:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: aws-elb-load-balance
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - !Ref Subnet1
      - !Ref Subnet2

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref VPC

  Listener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref VPC
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalance
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  MyRDS:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref RBDBInstance2
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocStore
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !GetAtt 
      - AWSBucket
      - WebsiteURL
    Description: URL website host S3

  EC2InstanceNet1:
    Value: !Ref EC2Net1

  EC2InstanceNet2:
    Value: !Ref EC2Net2

  S3BucketName:
    Value: !Ref AWSBucket

  DBInstanceId:
    Value: !Ref RBDBInstance2
```

Comment: You haven't specified what exactly value of `ACL` are you using, thus its not possible to advise what causes your second problem.

Comment: I specified the ACL on the CloudFoundation parameters prompt when creating the stack. ACL chosen was value: PublicReadWrite

Answer (score 2):

Target Group is not VPC. So in

```
TargetGroupArn: !Ref VPC
```

instead of `VPC` you have to reference [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html) that you have to create as you don't have any.

Comment: so you are saying that I am missing the ElasticLoadBalanceingV2 TargetGroup that needs to have !Ref to my VPC resource?

Comment: Is this correct reference:   TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

Comment: I don't see any property named: TargetGroupArn for reference to VPC?

Comment: Or should I include both: as in:::     Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref VPC

Comment: @manager_matt Please check documentation of `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup` that I linked. It does not have `TargetGroupArn` property. The documentation has also examples of how correct `TargetGroup` looks like.